How can I summarize differently for 2 groups of columns in data.table (R)?
I have some football code that uses data sets that are updated every week, now they have become really large data frames and I needed to convert them into data tables.
The problem is with this part of the code, I don't know how to replicate the result in data tables. The idea is that columns whose name appears in the non_percent vector are summarized in a certain way, while those that appear in the percent vector are summarized differently.
player_matchLogs %>%
    group_by(Player, Tier, Sex) %>%
    summarize(
        Min = round(sum(Min, na.rm = TRUE) / 90),
        across(non_percent, ~ round(sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE) / Min, 2)),
        across(percent, ~ round(mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 2))
    )

Here's a glimpse of the dataset:
> glimpse(player_matchLogs)
Rows: 41
Columns: 130
$ League                   <chr> "Premier League", "Pr…
$ Match_Date               <chr> "2023-08-11", "2023-0…
$ Matchweek                <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, …
$ Home_Team                <chr> "Burnley", "Mancheste…
$ Home_Formation           <chr> "5-4-1", "4-2-3-1", "…
$ Home_Score               <dbl> 0, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, …
$ Home_xG                  <dbl> 0.3, 1.0, 0.7, 2.2, 0…
$ Home_Goals               <chr> "Anass Zaroury · 90+4…
$ Home_Yellow_Cards        <chr> "0", "1", "4", "2", "…
$ Home_Red_Cards           <chr> "1", "0", "0", "0", "…
$ Away_Team                <chr> "Manchester City", "N…
$ Away_Formation           <chr> "4-2-3-1", "4-3-3", "…
$ Away_Score               <dbl> 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 1, …
$ Away_xG                  <dbl> 1.9, 0.3, 3.5, 1.4, 3…
$ Away_Goals               <chr> "Erling Haaland · 4&r…
$ Away_Yellow_Cards        <chr> "0", "5", "0", "4", "…
$ Away_Red_Cards           <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "…
$ Game_URL                 <chr> "https://fbref.com/en…
$ Team                     <chr> "Manchester City", "M…
$ Home_Away                <chr> "Away", "Home", "Away…
$ Player                   <chr> "Julián Álvarez", "Ju…
$ Player_Href              <chr> "/en/players/15ab5a2b…
$ Player_Num               <dbl> 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 1…
$ Nation                   <chr> "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", …
$ Pos                      <chr> "LM,AM,FW", "AM", "AM…
$ Age                      <chr> "23-192", "23-200", "…
$ Min                      <dbl> 90, 90, 90, 89, 90, 5…
$ Cmp_Total                <dbl> 36, 24, 34, 28, 52, 1…
$ Att_Total                <dbl> 44, 31, 52, 37, 63, 2…
$ Cmp_percent_Total        <dbl> 81.8, 77.4, 65.4, 75.…
$ TotDist_Total            <dbl> 490, 283, 542, 355, 7…
$ PrgDist_Total            <dbl> 113, 83, 102, 100, 18…
$ Cmp_Short                <dbl> 22, 18, 20, 15, 30, 1…
$ Att_Short                <dbl> 25, 20, 24, 19, 34, 1…
$ Cmp_percent_Short        <dbl> 88.0, 90.0, 83.3, 78.…
$ Cmp_Medium               <dbl> 7, 5, 11, 6, 13, 4, 5…
$ Att_Medium               <dbl> 9, 9, 17, 7, 14, 4, 8…
$ Cmp_percent_Medium       <dbl> 77.8, 55.6, 64.7, 85.…
$ Cmp_Long                 <dbl> 3, 0, 3, 2, 5, 2, 2, …
$ Att_Long                 <dbl> 5, 1, 8, 4, 11, 5, 6,…
$ Cmp_percent_Long         <dbl> 60.0, 0.0, 37.5, 50.0…
$ Ast                      <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, …
$ xAG                      <dbl> 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 0…
$ xA                       <dbl> 0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0…
$ KP                       <dbl> 6, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, …
$ Final_Third              <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 0, 2, …
$ PPA                      <dbl> 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, …
$ CrsPA                    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, …
$ PrgP                     <dbl> 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, …
$ Sex                      <chr> "M", "M", "M", "M", "…
$ Tier                     <chr> "1st", "1st", "1st", …
$ Att                      <dbl> 44, 31, 52, 37, 63, 2…
$ Live_Pass_Types          <dbl> 38, 29, 40, 34, 55, 2…
$ Dead_Pass_Types          <dbl> 6, 2, 11, 2, 8, 3, 8,…
$ FK_Pass_Types            <dbl> 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 6, …
$ TB_Pass_Types            <dbl> 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, …
$ Sw_Pass_Types            <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Crs_Pass_Types           <dbl> 5, 3, 12, 1, 9, 3, 5,…
$ TI_Pass_Types            <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, …
$ CK_Pass_Types            <dbl> 2, 0, 9, 1, 5, 2, 2, …
$ In_Corner_Kicks          <dbl> 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, …
$ Out_Corner_Kicks         <dbl> 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, …
$ Str_Corner_Kicks         <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Cmp_Outcomes             <dbl> 36, 24, 34, 28, 52, 1…
$ Off_Outcomes             <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Blocks_Outcomes          <dbl> 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, …
$ Tkl_Tackles              <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, …
$ TklW_Tackles             <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, …
$ `Def 3rd_Tackles`        <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, …
$ `Mid 3rd_Tackles`        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `Att 3rd_Tackles`        <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, …
$ Tkl_Challenges           <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, …
$ Att_Challenges           <dbl> 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, …
$ Tkl_percent_Challenges   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1…
$ Lost_Challenges          <dbl> 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Blocks_Blocks            <dbl> 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, …
$ Sh_Blocks                <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Pass_Blocks              <dbl> 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, …
$ Int                      <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `Tkl+Int`                <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, …
$ Clr                      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, …
$ Err                      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Touches_Touches          <dbl> 53, 40, 67, 41, 67, 3…
$ `Def Pen_Touches`        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, …
$ `Def 3rd_Touches`        <dbl> 2, 5, 2, 0, 5, 3, 3, …
$ `Mid 3rd_Touches`        <dbl> 22, 19, 17, 23, 18, 8…
$ `Att 3rd_Touches`        <dbl> 29, 16, 49, 19, 44, 2…
$ `Att Pen_Touches`        <dbl> 4, 3, 9, 2, 4, 2, 2, …
$ Live_Touches             <dbl> 53, 40, 67, 41, 67, 3…
$ Att_Take_Ons             <dbl> 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, …
$ Succ_Take_Ons            <dbl> 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, …
$ Succ_percent_Take_Ons    <dbl> NA, 66.7, NA, 100.0, …
$ Tkld_Take_Ons            <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, …
$ Tkld_percent_Take_Ons    <dbl> NA, 33.3, NA, 0.0, NA…
$ Carries_Carries          <dbl> 25, 25, 44, 26, 45, 1…
$ TotDist_Carries          <dbl> 104, 130, 156, 159, 2…
$ PrgDist_Carries          <dbl> 50, 62, 91, 114, 158,…
$ PrgC_Carries             <dbl> 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 0, 0, …
$ Final_Third_Carries      <dbl> 2, 1, 6, 3, 4, 1, 0, …
$ CPA_Carries              <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, …
$ Mis_Carries              <dbl> 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Dis_Carries              <dbl> 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, …
$ Rec_Receiving            <dbl> 40, 32, 46, 35, 47, 2…
$ PrgR_Receiving           <dbl> 6, 5, 10, 5, 7, 2, 4,…
$ CrdY                     <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, …
$ CrdR                     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ `2CrdY`                  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Fls                      <dbl> 1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, …
$ Fld                      <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, …
$ Off                      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Crs                      <dbl> 5, 3, 12, 1, 9, 3, 5,…
$ TklW                     <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, …
$ PKwon                    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, …
$ PKcon                    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ OG                       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Recov                    <dbl> 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, …
$ Won_Aerial_Duels         <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
$ Lost_Aerial_Duels        <dbl> 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, …
$ Won_percent_Aerial_Duels <dbl> 25.0, NA, NA, NA, 0.0…
$ Id                       <chr> "20230811ManchesterCi…
$ Team_Formation           <chr> "4-2-3-1", "4-2-3-1",…
$ Rival_Formation          <chr> "5-4-1", "4-3-3", "3-…
$ Team_xG                  <dbl> 1.9, 1.0, 3.5, 2.2, 3…
$ Rival_xG                 <dbl> 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 1.4, 0…
$ Team_YCards              <chr> "0", "1", "0", "2", "…
$ Rival_YCards             <chr> "0", "5", "4", "4", "…
$ Team_RCards              <chr> "0", "0", "0", "0", "…
$ Rival_RCards             <chr> "1", "0", "0", "0", "…
$ Team_Goals               <dbl> 3, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, …
$ Rival_Goals              <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, …

Thank you and sorry if this is a stupid question.

If the concern is over performance, you might try the new package duckplyr as a way to translate dplyr chains to use duckdb, which in recent benchmarks is 3-6x faster than data.table https://duckdblabs.github.io/db-benchmark/ for large data. (in those cases at least a few orders of magnitude larger than you have here)

I don't understand how to use it in this scenario to be honest

You would install the package from CRAN, then add duckplyr::as_duckplyr_df() %>% before the group_by() and see if the performance is any better. I'm not sure what to expect but it's easy to try.

You could try dtplyr, which lets you use dplyr code with data.table as a backend:
library(dplyr)
library(dtplyr)

player_matchLogs %>%
    lazy_dt() %>%
    group_by(Player, Tier, Sex) %>%
    summarize(
        Min = round(sum(Min, na.rm = TRUE) / 90),
        across(all_of(non_percent), ~ round(sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE) / Min, 2)),
        across(all_of(percent), ~ round(mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), 2))
    ) %>%
    as_tibble()


One possible translation to data.table is as below:
f <- function(df, pp, np) {
  minvalue = round(sum(df[['Min']], na.rm=T)/90)
  cbind(
    data.table(Min = minvalue),
    df[, lapply(.SD, \(s) round(sum(s, na.rm=T)/minvalue, 2)), .SDcols = np],
    df[, lapply(.SD, \(s) round(sum(s, na.rm=T),2)), .SDcols = pp]
  )
}

setDT(player_matchLogs)
player_matchLogs[, f(.SD, percent, non_percent), .(Player, Tier, Sex)]

